# Can I buy on amazon with an empty prepaid card?

Tags: credit-card

Why did I receive an email when I buy a laptop with nothing in my prepaid card?

"Thank you for shopping with us. We’ll send a confirmation when your item ships."

Why did I receive the email when I don't have money?

Comment: This question is incoherent. Can you please rewrite it so you are clearly posing a question, a question we can answer about personal finance?

Comment: This question is tagged "credit card", but the question body mentions prepaid card. Which one was it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect you would be able to **order** something on Amazon with an empty card.  Amazon only charges your card when it's going to ship your order so they wouldn't have noticed the card was empty.

However, before the order actually ships the card will be charged--which will fail--and they won't ship the laptop.

Answer (score -2):

One of my clients experienced something similar. If you have a location on which to click in the email, examine it for characteristics of spam or phishing. A faked email serves to entice you to use the embedded links, which are not truly related to the vendor, in this case, Amazon, and will re-direct you to a site for the purposes of separating you from your money.

Comment: This really doesn't apply.  The OP did buy something from Amazon, albeit with a card that is going to be rejected (per @Loren Pechtel's answer).  Amazon does send messages like that when you purchase things.  If scam artists have managed to hack into Amazon's order database, they have much better ways of extracting money than phishing a few customers :-)